# Is there any working Apache module to implment NTLM on Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am trying to configure NTLM authentication for an internal site that is running on Apache/Ubuntu Jammy. I was able to implement `ldap` authentication. Still, I want to make the login/auth process smooth as the user is already logged into his work computer using their domain credentials.

I tried installing the Apache module via `apt` based on some older documentation that I found via Google, but the packages are no longer available.

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-auth-ntlm  
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-auth-ntlm
```

Could you please suggest to me how I can implement NTLM-based authentication for my Apache proxy server, which is running on Debian-based Linux (Ubuntu)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).